# Laravel Backpack select2_multiple not Displaying Correctly

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I'm working with Backpack for Laravel, and implemented a select2_multiple field. The field works correctly, though it doesn't display properly at all. It's defined as:

```
    $this->crud->addField([       // Select2Multiple = n-n relationship (with pivot table)
        'label' => "Categories",
        'type' => 'select2_multiple',
        'name' => 'categories', // the method that defines the relationship in your Model
        'entity' => 'categories', // the method that defines the relationship in your Model
        'attribute' => 'title', // foreign key attribute that is shown to user
        'model' => "App\Models\Category", // foreign key model
        'pivot' => true // on create&update, do you need to add/delete pivot table entries?
    ]);
```

The pivot tables exist, as do the relationships on the models. The field shows for a second, and then in quickly hidden on page load (I guess by some JS). You can see below the 'categories' label, there's just white space:

[image]

I can, however, click in the white space and it will then appear and allow me to select categories as expected (though it displays rather strangely):

[image]

This is all default functionality, I haven't edited the select2_multiple template or any of the JS. Why is this displaying so poorly?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it was a bug that [has since been fixed](https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/CRUD/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#fixed-1). A `composer update` should fix it for you.

Comment: I just ran a composer update to test, and the same issue still exists unfortunately.

Comment: Hmm... have you published the select2_multiple field? If there's a file in your ```resources/views/backpack/crud/fields/select2_multiple.blade.php```, Backpack will pick up that one, instead of the updated one from the package.

Answer (score 0):

Is the model correct?
Maybe should be

```
'model' => "App\Category", // foreign key model
```